# SQL Server on Kubernetes ReadWriteOnce.. multiple nodes but only one can attach to PersistentVolume?

Tags: sql-server, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-volumes, gce-persistent-disk

2 nodes on GKE.
Persistent Disk on GCE (outside of cluster) being used as PV.
Want to create a StatefulSet of SQL Server following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-kubernetes-best-practices-statefulsets?view=sql-server-ver16).
This will generate 1 SQL Server container in one pod per node. So total 1 instance spread over 2 nodes in 2 pods in 2 containers.
Concerned that a PV can only be listed as RWO (ReadWriteOnce) and can only attach to one node at a time. I have seen that GKE only allows RWX (ReadWriteMany) on something called a Filestore, not on a PV in GCE. Filestore may be an option but I have not explored it.

Questions follow:
If I have a request coming in to the SQL Server on the second node, how does it write to the PV?
If the "2nd" SQL Server does not write to the PV, do I need to generate another PV for it to write to? If so, how does it stay in sync with the first? No HA groups.

Have not yet deployed my yaml to K8s

Comment: Refer to this [doc1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) and [doc 2](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks)helpful to resolve your issue

Comment: In the MSFT doc you reference, if you increase the number of replicas >1, you are actually creating two independent MSSQL instances each with their own persistent volume.  They would not be sharing the same volume.